# Cannot print out []byte data MQTT

Tags: go, struct, channel

I have a function that takes in JSON data sent using MQTT and unmarshalls it into a struct. I then marshal the struct into a JSON for the purpose of checking whether it holds the desired values. My issue is that I am unable to print out the data after I marshalled it.

Here is my code:

```
func VirtualDevice(client MQTT.Client, deviceID string) *VD {

var data []byte

sensorData := new(VD)

var g MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Payload(), &sensorData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {

        //fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *sensorData) 

    }
}
client.Subscribe("data-update/"+deviceID, 0, g)
data, _ = json.Marshal(*sensorData)
fmt.Println(string(data)) //not printing anything
return sensorData
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this isn't printing out? Thank you.

Comment: is the `MessageHandler` executed in a goroutine? or is `client.Subscribe` executed in a goroutine?

Comment: ... because if not, then  `c <- data` will block `client.Subscribe` from ever exiting. So the lines of code after it won't be executed.

Comment: ... try it with a buffered channel, e.g. `make(chan []byte, 1)`, they block only when full, so sending one piece of data should be ok for your purpose.

Comment: @mkopriva It doesn't seem to work. This is running in a loop, so I constantly receive data. All I really want to do is be able to return the data I receive, so I tried using a channel, but if there are other ways then I'd love some help with that.

Comment: what is running in a loop?

Comment: ... also your example unnecessarily unmarshals bytes into a struct and then marshal that struct back into bytes, just pass the payload to the channel.

Comment: @mkopriva I edited my code to serve another purpose. Basically I want to return a pointer to an **instance** of the struct. And the purpose of my marshalling it is just to see the contents of what is in that struct. However, it's not printing out anything :( Any ideas on why?

Comment: i haven't used the mqtt package so I'm not 100% sure, but I think the messages are being sent to the handler concurrently, which means that `json.Marshal` and `return` are executed before the client receives a message and passes it to the handler. But looking at their documentation it seems to me that you might be able to "wait" for the message by using the token that's returned from the `Subscribe` method. Try experimenting with that if that doesn't work make sure to add mqtt tag to your question and maybe someone with more knowledge about the package can chime in.